# Iterate through an array and use yield properly

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out how to iterate through an array in Ruby and perform actions based upon the values (and figure out how to use `yield`. Below is the code I have so far, however this is not working. Can someone help point me in the right direction?

```
each_odd("Odd")

def each_odd
  array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
  array.map {|x| 
   if (x % 2 != 0) do x = yield 
   else x = "Even"
   end}
end
```

I am expecting this to return the following array: `["Odd", "Even", "Odd", "Even"]`

Comment: "this is not working" is about as helpful as "xyzzyplughtwisty" in terms of indicating the problem :-) Every problem report should have (1) a complete minimal sample exhibiting the problem, (2) the expected behaviour and (3) the actual behaviour.

Comment: That's about what I get for an error message. I get the code I wrote given back to me in the command line with a 'carrot' underneath the `yield`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use yield you have to pass a block.

And you can use `{}` blocks

```
each_odd { 'Odd' } #=> ["Odd", "Even", "Odd", "Even"]
```

Or `do .. end` blocks

```
each_odd do
  'Odd'
end
#=> ["Odd", "Even", "Odd", "Even"]
```

And here is how to implement the method

```
def each_odd
  [1, 2, 3, 4].map do |x| 
    (x % 2 != 0) ? yield(x) : 'Even'
  end
end
```

When called `yield` it will evaluate what's inside the block and return it to the context, also you can pass parameters to the block like so:

```
yield(x)
```

and then you could do something like

```
each_odd { |num| "#{num} is Odd" } #=> ["1 is Odd", "Even", "3 is Odd", "Even"]
```

Comment: I understand it is easier to not use yield, however I am trying to learn Ruby. Right now, specifically how to iterate through and array and use yield.

Comment: Ok, I will give you the exemple with yield

Comment: This is a really bad example if your intention is learning, but anyway, it's your education not mine.

Comment: @aromero true. But when at beginning it's good already to just understand a way that it runs and does what you expect. Even if it's really a dummy exercise.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in yielding in this case, simply use a map

```
[1,2,3,4].map{|x| x % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd" }
```

Comment: I'm trying to use yield to transform the array from `[1, 2, 3, 4]` to `["Odd", "Even", "Odd", "Even"]`

Comment: I understand it is easier to not use yield, however I am trying to learn how to Ruby. Right now, specifically how to iterate through and array and use yield.

Comment: Try to formulate a good example for using yield then. How about recreating the map? You can try that, and then apply it to this example.

Comment: `x % 2 == 0` could be replaced with just `x.even?`.